# Couldn't run the python application based on TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import Tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

pad = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], ["C", 0, "S"]]
passcode = ""

def append_passcode(value):
    global passcode
    if len(passcode) == 4:
        passcode = passcode[1:]
    passcode += value

def clear():
    global passcode
    passcode = ""

def submit():
    global passcode
    if passcode == "1234":
        msgBox.showinfo("Login Attempt", "Successful")
        passcode = ""
    else:
        msgBox.showinfo("Login Attempt", "Failed")
        passcode = ""

main_window = tk.Tk()

btns = []
row_placement = 0
for line in pad:
    col_placement = 0
    for number in line:
        btn_command = partial(append_passcode, str(number))
        btn = tk.Button(main_window, text=str(number), width=10, command=btn_command)
        btns.append(btn)
        btn.grid(row=row_placement, column=col_placement)
        col_placement += 1
    row_placement += 1

#Setting C to clear the passcode function
btns[-3].config(command=clear)

#Setting S to submit passcode
btns[-1].config(command=submit)
```

I'm writing an numpad application where user must enter the correct 4 digit code to access application. when the test code runs, the GUI does not appear.  What needs to be done to get this code to function?

Comment: If my answer help you, could you please press the green tick

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you've done wrong:

- Misspelled tkinter
- Not included

  ```
  main_window.mainloop()
  ```

Try this code

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

pad = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], ["C", 0, "S"]]
passcode = ""

def append_passcode(value):
    global passcode
    if len(passcode) == 4:
        passcode = passcode[1:]
    passcode += value

def clear():
    global passcode
    passcode = ""

def submit():
    global passcode
    if passcode == "1234":
        msgBox.showinfo("Login Attempt", "Successful")
        passcode = ""
    else:
        msgBox.showinfo("Login Attempt", "Failed")
        passcode = ""

main_window = tk.Tk()

btns = []
row_placement = 0
for line in pad:
    col_placement = 0
    for number in line:
        btn_command = partial(append_passcode, str(number))
        btn = tk.Button(main_window, text=str(number), width=10, command=btn_command)
        btns.append(btn)
        btn.grid(row=row_placement, column=col_placement)
        col_placement += 1
    row_placement += 1

#Setting C to clear the passcode function
btns[-3].config(command=clear)

#Setting S to submit passcode
btns[-1].config(command=submit)

main_window.mainloop()
```

Now your window should appear.

Hope this helps and feel free to comment any questions.

Comment: tkinter may not be misspelled- they have the correct spelling for python2.